# Google webmaster Index Status. Total Indexed=0

Tags: search-engine-indexing, google-index

I previously changed my domain from `www.visualstudiolearn.blogspot.com` to `www.visualstudiolearn.com`.

I had around 300 posts with the previous domain name and most of them where showing up on Google. Now that I have changed my domain name the index status shows total indexed as 0 and when I go to the advanced tab it says 304 (not selected) and 217 blocked by robots.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a robots.txt file blocking any files or directories or are the 217 files things you purposely don't want indexed?

Comment: Did you inform Google of your new domain?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have a few issues going on.

- For one, Google is seeing a lot of duplicate content. If you only have 300 posts, and they are seing 521 (especially the 304 not selected), you are definitely having duplicate content issues. That could be for a lot of different reasons. See this SEOmoz article for more info: [Duplicate Content](http://www.seomoz.org/learn-seo/duplicate-content)
- For two, if you moved the posts over to the new domain it will take a while for Google to re-crawl and re-index the pages under their new URL's. This could take weeks especially if your site isn't properly optimized and Googlebot isn't giving your site a big enough crawl budget. Too much duplicate content will effect this.
- The 217 blocked by robots is almost definitely due to pages being blocked in your robots.txt file

Answer (score 2):

If you have not submitted any sitemap it might take more than 30-45 days fro google to crawl, with sitemap it usually takes 15-20. But there is no way to find out when google will crawl the webpage.

Check all your robots.txt and see if any of them disallow any robots or not.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to implement 301 redirection from old URL to your new URL.
There's no need to worry once you already created a 301 in you site.